# Simplepie: Sort RSS posts by date last updated

Tags: php, parsing, rss, simplepie

I'm trying to sort the posts of an rss feed by the date they were last updated, using simplepie to parse the feed. I was thinking I could use the "get item tags method", like so:

`$feed_object->get_item_tags("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "updated");`,

in order to create an array of update dates, and then sort them somehow. However, get_item_tags() throws the following:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimplePie::get_item_tags()`

So: Is there an easier/better way to do this, and what is wrong with my usage of get_item_tags()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this way?

```
$item = $feed->get_item(0));   // the first item in feed; do it in loop
$data = $item->get_item_tags("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", "updated");
```

[get_item_tags](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/start) is an item level function.